# When it says "if an item..."

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]When it says "if an item is found in the ..." does that mean it's applying to a single product or is that just worded funny?

I keep getting my discount of Buy one get one applying to the one product. But we have 93 variations that I'd like to include as the offer not just 2 of each.

So one category, 93 products, get any one and get any other free is my goal. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Daniel, we might need some more information. Where do you see this message, what are you trying to accomplish. Maybe include some screenshots

Comment: I added the picture. Like I said, I'm trying to get Product A, Product B in the cart. Then make Product C free.

They can all be AAA, ABC, AAC, BBC, etc...I just need it to not make it stricty AAA, or BBB, or CCC.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Daniel, what this is saying. Is if all combinations of the conditions are true for A product in the cart.

Comment: I'm afraid that if I'm understanding you correctly this is not possible with default Magento since you cannot use wildcards. Im I correct in understanding you?

Comment: Sander - - What a huge bummer. I thought shopping cart rules would apply to the shopping cart contents and not looking at individual products. What's a good way to do this then?

Comment: @Daniel, what it appears you are trying to do is a quasi BOGO (buy one, get one) promotion. By default Magento is not really setup to handle this. There are 3rd party extensions which do provide this functionality.

Comment: @elrik - it's really just buy 2 get 1, and of a certain category. Where it says "if an item..." it should adjust to say "if items are..." as well.

Comment: For posterity I just want to say it works the way I want but I dont want to have my cart QTY to have to be the same product. If you're getting something free, it's likely you're not going to buy 3 of the same exact thing.

Comment: Hey Daniel, could you add your last comment as answer and accept? This way you close the question and we keep the `answered` rate up :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at both your question, and the comments you posted on your question, you can probably pull off what you want this way:

- **Condition:** Product is in Category A.
- **Action:** *Apply:* Buy X get Y free, *Discount Qty Step (Buy X):* 2, if Product is in Category A.

That will require the customer to have any three products from Category A in their cart, and 1 of them will be free. This will work if they have 3 products in their cart, or 6, or 9, etc. If you want to limit it to only one free item, set *Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To:* 1.

Comment: Tyler - that does work only the promotion is working like A x3, B x3, C x3 when I would like A x1, B x1, and C x1 (or any combination that totals 3)